# Data tables, get data , js

Tags: javascript, api, get, datatables

I'm using [DataTables](http://datatables.net), to do a dataTable, I receve JSON from my API and in Js I use this code...

```
 // Variable to send in Get//
var id = $cookieStore.get('uid');


$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example').dataTable( {
                "sDom": "<'row'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",

                "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",

                "bProcessing": true,


                "sAjaxSource" : "http://localhost:3347/api/controlerX",


             "aoColumns": [
                 { "mData": "1Fild"},
                 { "mData": "2Fild"},
                 { "mData": "3Fild"},
                 { "mData": "4Fild"},
                 { "mData": "5Fild"},
                 { "mData": "6Fild"},
                 { "mData": "7Fild"},
                 { "mData": "8Fild" }
    ]
,
    "oLanguage": {
        "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_  page"
    }
```

How can I send my Id in my Get request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
"sAjaxSource" : 
    "http://localhost:3347/api/controlerX?id=" + $cookieStore.get('uid'),
```

Comment: I had already tried, but I was receiving the data the wrong way ...

Problem solved, tank you!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put in $.ajax({}) and try to send the id you want to the server side resource.